# Access to Excel VBA Loop Running Very Slowly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a macro in Access that opens a designated folder with about 50 .csv files, opens them one at a time, reformats them, then copy and pastes them into a master spreadsheet. In each of the .csv files the first three columns are Project, Serial Number, and Location. This information is the same all the way down the column (one unique value for each), and it takes a very long time to run. The location is a set value for all of the .csv files but the serial number and location change with each. The .csv files each have the relevant location and serial number in them, so basically I'm just designating the range and using a simple `For` loop to set each value in the range to the value of the cell that contains the loc/serial number.

Here's my code:

```
Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, savePath As String)

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long

    'Do Stuff with each file in folders
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        Dim wbData, wbMaster As Workbook
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Set wbMaster = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(savePath)
        Set wbData = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
        Dim masterSheet, curDataSheet As Worksheet
        Set masterSheet = wbMaster.Sheets(1)

        For Each sht In wbData.Sheets()
            Set curDataSheet = sht

            'Only want sheets with longer than 4 characters
            If Len(curDataSheet.Name) > 4 Then
                Dim lastRow As Long
                Dim masterLastRow As Long
                wbMaster.Activate
                masterSheet.Activate
                masterSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate
                'masterLastRow = masterSheet.Rows.count("A")
                masterLastRow = masterSheet.Cells(masterSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Dim cell1 As Boolean
                If masterSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                cell1 = False
                Else
                cell1 = True
                End If

                wbData.Activate
                curDataSheet.Activate

                    lastRow = curDataSheet.Cells(curDataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                                Dim bot, bot2, i As Integer
                                Dim rng, refrng As Range
                                Dim loc, sn As String

                                'Add first 3 and last 4 columns, give them titles
                                curDataSheet.Columns("A:C").Insert shift:=xlToRight
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 1).Value = "Project ID"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 2).Value = "Serial_Number"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 3).Value = "Location"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 9).Value = "Date_Time"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 10).Value = "DT Concat"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 11).Value = "DT"
                                curDataSheet.Cells(12, 12).Value = "ST"

                                loc = curDataSheet.Cells(2, 4)
                                sn = curDataSheet.Cells(6, 4)

                                'define last row
                                bot = curDataSheet.Range("D" & curDataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                'second bot pointer is bot -13 because of the extra 12 rows at the top
                                bot2 = bot - 12
                                'set ranges for loop
                                Set rng = curDataSheet.Range("A13:A" & bot)
                                Set refrng = curDataSheet.Range("D14:D" & bot)

                                'loop through ranges to set values
                                For i = 1 To bot2
                                    rng(i, 1).Value = "MSA DRA"
                                Next i

                                Set rng = curDataSheet.Range("B13:B" & bot)
                                For i = 1 To bot2
                                   rng(i, 1).Value = loc
                                Next i

                                Set rng = curDataSheet.Range("C13:C" & bot)
                                For i = 1 To bot2
                                   rng(i, 1).Value = sn
                                Next i

                                'Delete top 11 rows
                                curDataSheet.Rows("1:11").EntireRow.Delete

                Dim copyRange As Range

                If masterLastRow = 1 And Not cell1 Then

                    Set copyRange = curDataSheet.Range(curDataSheet.Cells(1, 1), curDataSheet.Cells(lastRow, 24))

                    copyRange.Copy

                Else

                    Set copyRange = curDataSheet.Range(curDataSheet.Cells(2, 1), curDataSheet.Cells(lastRow, 24))

                    copyRange.Copy

                End If

                wbData.Activate
                masterSheet.Activate
                Dim pasteRange As Range
                If masterLastRow = 1 Then


                     Set pasteRange = masterSheet.Range(masterSheet.Cells(1, 1), masterSheet.Cells(1, 1))
                    pasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                Else
                     Set pasteRange = masterSheet.Range(masterSheet.Cells(masterLastRow + 1, 1), masterSheet.Cells(masterLastRow + 1, 1))
                    pasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                End If
               End If
        Next sht

        wbMaster.Save
        wbMaster.Close
        wbData.Close savechanges:=False
        xlApp.Quit

    Next objFile

    'Recurse through subfolders

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, savePath)
    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

When I execute this code in Excel, it runs instantly, but when I put it in the Access macro and run it from there, it takes forever to run. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show some more of the code?  If this is in Access, I would be expecting you to create an Excel Application object, etc, so that you can use `Sheets`, `Rows` and `Cells` in that object.  The solution to your problem may be as simple as correctly referring to the appropriate objects that you created.

Comment: You could probably get rid of all loops. Use arrays instead, iterating ranges and assigning cell values one by one is quite possibly the single slowest thing you can do with the Excel object model. If your code works as intended, just not efficiently, posting the actual procedure (heck, the entire module!) on [codereview.se] can teach you a trick or two. SO is better suited for *specific* programming issues / bugs.

Comment: As @YowE3K describes, this is Excel VBA, not Access VBA. Please post the full entire relevant code block, one that is compilable by anyone including source data and desired results (whcih even better illustrates your text explanation). This together creates a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just added the rest of the code. I only put the excel vba because that is the only part that is slow. regardless it is there now.

Comment: The declaration of `wbData` as a `Variant` could be causing issues.  Try declaring it as a `Workbook` instead.  Also declare `mastersheet` as a `Worksheet`.  I suspect the main culprit though will be the `Activate` statements.  (As far as I can see, they aren't even needed, so I'm not sure why you have them there.)

Comment: And. as @Mat'sMug said, you can use statements such as `curDataSheet.Range("A13:A" & bot).Value = "MSA DRA"`, `curDataSheet.Range("B13:B" & bot).Value = loc`, and `curDataSheet.Range("B13:B" & bot).Value = sn` to get rid of your loops.  If `bot` is a largish number that could help substantially.